# Trouble Testing setup.py for Cython Extension Module - ImportError and Test Failure

Tags: python, numpy, compilation, pytest, cython

I'm currently facing challenges while attempting to test the `setup.py` script for a Cython project using `pytest`. Despite following guidance and examples, I'm encountering an `ImportError` and test failure. Here's what I have so far:

1. **Project Structure**:

```
my_project/
├── setup.py
├── cython_numpy_test.pyx
└── tests/
    └── test_setup.py
```

2. **cython_numpy_test.pyx**:

```py
# cython_numpy_test.pyx
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

# Define a Cython function that calculates the element-wise product of two arrays
def elementwise_product():
    # ... (cython_numpy_test.pyx content)
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    elementwise_product()
```

3. **setup.py**:

```py
# setup.py
import os
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy as np

def build_extension():
    # Define the name of the original .pyx file
    original_filename = "cython_numpy_test.pyx"

    # Get the current directory where setup.py is located
    current_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    # Path to the original .pyx file in the current directory
    original_filepath = os.path.join(current_directory, original_filename)

    # Extract the base name and extension of the original file
    base_name, ext = os.path.splitext(original_filename)

    # Create a new file name and directory
    new_filename = f"PYX_{base_name}{ext}"
    new_directory = "PYX_archives"

    # Create the new directory if it doesn't exist
    if not os.path.exists(new_directory):
        os.makedirs(new_directory)

    # Configuration for building Cython extension
    setup(
        name=base_name,  # Extracted base name without extension
        ext_modules=cythonize(original_filepath),  # Compile the original .pyx file
        include_dirs=[np.get_include()]  # Include NumPy headers
    )

    # Rename and move the original .pyx file to the new directory
    os.rename(
        original_filepath,
        os.path.join(new_directory, new_filename)
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    build_extension()
```

- Imports modules:

  - `os`: Operating system functionality.
  - `setup` from `setuptools`: Define package info.
  - `cythonize` from `Cython.Build`: Compile `.pyx` to C extension.
  - `numpy as np`: Include NumPy headers.
- Defines `build_extension()`:

  - Builds Cython extension.
  - Constructs paths and names.
  - Configures build using `setup()`.
  - Renames and moves original `.pyx` file.
- Conditional execution:

  - `build_extension()` runs when script is executed.
- Rename and Move .pyx File:

  - The original `.pyx` file is renamed to the newly constructed filename.
  - The renamed `.pyx` file is then moved to a directory named `PYX_archives`.
- Conditional Execution:

  - The code inside the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block ensures that the `build_extension()` function is executed only when the script is run directly.

4. **test_setup.py**:

```py
# tests/test_setup.py
import os
from pathlib import Path  # Adding pathlib.Path import
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..")))  # Add parent directory to sys.path
import setup
import pytest

def test_build_extension(tmpdir):
    temp_test_dir = Path(tmpdir.mkdir("test_setup"))  # Using pathlib.Path to create the directory
    
    # ... (rest of test_setup.py content)
```

5. **Error Message**:
   When I run the tests using `pytest`, the test `test_setup` fails with the following error message:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.11.4, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.2.0
rootdir: /app, configfile: pyproject.toml
plugins: pythonpath-0.7.4, anyio-3.7.1
collected 1 item                                                               

test_setup.py F                                                          [100%]

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
__________________________________ test_setup __________________________________

tmpdir = local('/tmp/pytest-of-root/pytest-7/test_setup0')

    def test_setup(tmpdir):
        temp_test_dir = tmpdir.mkdir("test_setup")
    
        # Define the name and directory of the original .pyx file
        original_filename = "numpy_permutations_combinations.pyx"
        original_path = temp_test_dir / original_filename
    
        # Create a sample .pyx file in the temporary directory
        with open(original_path, "w") as f:
            f.write("# Sample.pyx file content")
    
        # Run the setup.build_extension() function
>       setup.build_extension()

test_setup.py:48: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
../src/setup.py:28: in build_extension
    setup(
/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py:87: in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py:172: in setup
    ok = dist.parse_command_line()
/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py:474: in parse_command_line
    args = self._parse_command_opts(parser, args)
/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:1107: in _parse_command_opts
    nargs = _Distribution._parse_command_opts(self, parser, args)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <setuptools.dist.Distribution object at 0x7fd59b95bfd0>
parser = <distutils.fancy_getopt.FancyGetopt object at 0x7fd59c032250>
args = ['test_setup.py']

    def _parse_command_opts(self, parser, args):  # noqa: C901
        """Parse the command-line options for a single command.
        'parser' must be a FancyGetopt instance; 'args' must be the list
        of arguments, starting with the current command (whose options
        we are about to parse).  Returns a new version of 'args' with
        the next command at the front of the list; will be the empty
        list if there are no more commands on the command line.  Returns
        None if the user asked for help on this command.
        """
        # late import because of mutual dependence between these modules
        from distutils.cmd import Command
    
        # Pull the current command from the head of the command line
        command = args[0]
        if not command_re.match(command):
>           raise SystemExit("invalid command name '%s'" % command)
E           SystemExit: invalid command name 'test_setup.py'

/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py:526: SystemExit
----------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------
Compiling /app/src/cython_numpy_test.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing /app/src/cython_numpy_test.pyx
=============================== warnings summary ===============================
tests/test_setup.py::test_setup
  /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:381: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using '3str' for now (Py3). This has changed from earlier releases! File: /app/src/cython_numpy_test.pyx
    tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html
=========================== short test summary info ============================
FAILED test_setup.py::test_setup - SystemExit: invalid command name 'test_set...
========================= 1 failed, 1 warning in 1.07s =========================
```

I've confirmed that the `setup.py` script is correctly building the extension module when run standalone. However, when attempting to test it using `pytest`, I encounter an `ImportError` and a failure during the test. It seems that the issue is related to how I'm importing and using the `setup` module in the `test_setup.py` script.

My understanding is that the purpose of the `setup.py` script is to facilitate the compilation of the `cython_numpy_test.pyx` file into a Cython extension module. The script uses `setuptools` and `Cython` to accomplish this. I'm uncertain about how the `setup.build_extension()` function should be called in the context of the tests, and how I can ensure proper importing of modules and functions.

Could someone help shed light on what might be causing this error, how I can properly structure my tests for a Cython project using `pytest`, and any modifications needed to the `setup.py` script?